# Model Binding Dot Properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

How do I avoid directly accessing the Request.Form collection when the names of the fields in the form are dot properties, because I've made a view model that contains multiple types.

Now I have this method:

```
public ActionResult ChangeLineQty(int id, int quantity)
```

But the model binder doesn't see the quantity variable in the request.form collection, because the field name shows up as: `NewOrderLine.Quantity`

This particular form is an AJAX form that updates Quantity in the background, and it just uses the ID of the orderLine and the new quantity.

Comment: **[Please check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002022/is-there-any-good-reason-to-use-formcollection-instead-of-viewmodel)**

Answer (score 0):

Please Write Your Function Like This

```
public ActionResult ChangeLineQty(int id, NewOrderLine objNewOrderLine)
{
      int quantity=objNewOrderLine.Quantity;
}
```

Comment: I'm using @Html.Action to call this action. Can I pass along a full model? I though I can only send along routevalues.

Comment: you can pass model as route value Like this @Html.Action("Actionname","Controllername",Model) try this.More info Please Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608165/passing-model-to-html-action