# Is there any good reason to use FormCollection instead of ViewModel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I've inherited a code base written in ASP.Net MVC 4. Every post method takes a `FormCollection`. Aside from annoyance of having to access the values through quoted strings, it also leads to drawbacks such as not being able to use things like `ModelState.IsValid`, or `[AllowHtml]` attributes on my ViewModel properties. They actually did create ViewModel classes for each of their views, (though they are pretty much just direct wrappers around the actual Entity Framework Model classes), but they are only used for the GET methods.

Is there anything I'm missing about FormCollection that gives a reason why this may have actually been a good idea? It seems to only have drawbacks. I'd like to go through and "fix" it by using ViewModels instead. This would take a good bit of work because the ViewModels have properties that are interfaces and not concrete classes, which means either writing a custom binder or changing the ViewModels.

But perhaps there's something I'm missing where it makes sense to use FormCollection?

Comment: I've never faced a situation where I couldn't find a way to Model bind a form collection.

Comment: No, no, no, eradicate it from your codebase.

Comment: Is the code base using TryUpdateModel<modelType>(model)? If this is called first then you can use the methods boolean result to tell you if model binding was successful.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

> Is there any good reason to use FormCollection instead of ViewModel?

No. I have following issues.

**Issue - 1**

In case `FormCollection` is being used...It will be mandatory to `Type Cast` the `Primitive Type` Values un-necessarily because while getting the entry of specific Index of the `System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection`, value being returned is of type `String`. This situation will not come in case of Strongly Typed `View-Models`.

**Issue - 2**

When you submit the form and goes to `Post` Action Method,  and `View-Model` as Parameter exists in the Action method, you have the provision to send back the Posted Values to you `View`. Otherwise, write the code again to send back via `TempData/ViewData/ViewBag`

[image]

*View-Models are normal classes, created to bind data to-from Views*

**Issue - 3**

We have Data Annotations that can be implemented in `View Model` or `Custom Validations`.

[image]

*ASP.Net MVC simplifies model validatons using Data Annotation. Data Annotations are attributes thyat are applied over properties. We can create custom validation Attribute by inheriting the built-in Validation Attribute class.*

**Issue - 4**

Example you have the following **HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="textBox1" value="harsha" customAttr1 = "MyValue" />
```

***Question*** : How can we access the value of customAttr1 from the above eg from inside the controller

**Answer** : When a form get posted only the name and value of elements are posted back to the server.

**Alternatives** : Use a bit of jQuery to get the custom attribute values, and post that along with the form values to action method

Another option is to rather put what you got in your custom attributes in hidden controls

That's the reason, I would always prefer to use `View-Models`

Comment: All those cases are valid, but it still doesn't mean that there are no use cases where using FormCollection is valid.

Comment: And, you are ignoring fact that FormCollection is used toghether with UpdateModel/TryUpdateModel methods, which resolves all issues you counted. Additionally, you don't need Request object to reach FormCollection. You can make it input parameter of an action.

Comment: @Nenad : Please check *Issue - 4*. **My Question is** Will you really like to exclude the Client side validations using `Unobtrusive` from your project ? **[What's new in MVC3](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3#BM_JavaScript_and_Ajax_Improvements)**. If so then go on. I have already made it clear. ?

Comment: @PKKG: Why would you exclude unobtrusive validation? Fact that you use FormCollection as input parameter doesn't prevent you to render your ViewModel in the view (which would add validation attributes). Again, point is to use FormCollection+UpdateModel -> ViewModel, and from there everything else is exactly the same.

Comment: You also want to keep the View as Strongly Type and also in `Post` Action Method you want to keep `FormCollection` ???

Comment: @PKGG: If there is no ViewModel at all you cannot enforce validation, that's true. But advised usage of FormCollection is with ViewModel. It just moves model binding in your action code and gives you more control over binding process. I don't say this is recommended way of doing things, but it can have valid use cases.

Comment: @PKGG: Exactly - FormCollection is input parameter, ViewModel is constructed in your Action (UpdateModel, TryUpdateModel), and you pass it to strongly typed view. That's the pattern.

Comment: @Nenad : When you have View as strongly type. Why do you want to pass `FormCollection` in Post Action Method as parameter? Why not ViewModel?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32544/discussion-between-pkkg-and-nenad)

Comment: Issue 3 is incorrect. Request.Form can be mocked up using the MOQ unit test framework

Comment: @krilovich : As per my understanding and past experience it's a bad practise to use `Request.Form`. Instead you could use `FormCollection` as a parameter. This is a case when you are excluding the View Models from architecture.

Comment: There are some situations that `FormCollection` needs to be used: in 1 to N case, when the Controller has to mark a related entry with a validation error, how can be the line index be retrieved? For instance, I need to make a validation concerning the main entity and the related entity. I'll need also to use `ModelState.AddModelError()`. How can I provide the key (first argument)?

Answer (score 7):

The only advantage I can think of is if you want to use the automatically generated controller provided when you don't specify a EF model to be strongly typed to. In that case, your Create and Edit actions will use the FormCollection object as it is a reliable, pre-existing artifact of the framework to work with for this purpose. Perhaps the previous developer chose this option while creating his controllers, and stuck with it since Visual Studio must know what it's doing :)

But, in reality, I would never recommend this headstart of a few seconds. It's always better to build out viewmodels, I would recommend looking at the effort to move in that direction if only for maintenance purposes. With model binding and strongly typed views and html helpers, you are much more likely to reduce the number of run-time errors as a result of changing some magic string and not realizing it until your page blows up.

Comment: Thanks. My current maintenance headache is that when you post a page, and it fails server-side validation, thus returning the view, you then lose all the values that the user dynamically added. Took me over an hour to set up the ViewBag in such a way that I could re-render what the user had previously done... with a ViewModel, that should have been all handled automatically!

Comment: I agree with this, I think the strongly typed argument is more than enough to switch to models instead of the form collection. And IMO the ViewBag is horrible - it should be passed through with a model or not at all (there will be exceptions of course)

Comment: Having built a system that uses dynamically-bound lists of generic items to present user-defined forms and properly process the responses, I *still* think that it's better to learn the quirks of model binding and write a few extra lines of preprocessing than to work with `FormCollection`.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I see the general consensus here is that it isn't liked. To offer another perspective, I've always liked using the formcollection passed into the controller on POST actions. It offers the use of the TryUpdateModel method from the controller which will map the collection to your strongly typed class. TryUpdateModel also has overloads that allow you to white list the properties of the model that you want to allow to be updated.

```
if (TryUpdateModel(viewModel, new string[] { "Name" }))
{
    //Do something
}
```

It still allows all the model binding you want, but helps to keep anything other than the "Name" property on my viewmodel from being updated.

You can see more about the TryUpdateModel method here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.tryupdatemodel(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: Hmmm, so it sounds like TryUpdateModel basically does the same model binding that would have happened if the action method took the model as a parameter? This could at least be very useful for getting around the issue of the model not being populated in the current code base.

Comment: Corrective actions are better then Preventive actions or Preventive actions are better then Corrective actions ?

Comment: Very good example. Additionally, you might want to bind your Model ONLY from FormCollection, instead of default behavior (all value providers). UpdateModel/TryUpdateModel provides you with additional control.

Comment: @Nenad : Please check *Issue - 4*. **My Question is** Will you really like to exclude the Client side validations using **Unobtrusive** from your project ? **[What's new in MVC3](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3#BM_Model_Validation_Improvements)**

Answer (score 4):

There are always workarounds for getting away from a FormCollection lol.. you can have hidden fields bound to your view model variables in the form to your heart's content.

Form collections mostly emerge from the laziness of creating a view model but still end up taking time trying to get figure out how to get the values out of it in your controller :P

I think it was simply created in the very beginning of MVC as an alternative to using strongly typed views when having very simple forms - back in the days when everyone used ViewBag :) ... and once hey had it in there they couldn't just take it out as simple as that.

Maybe you can use it if you are absolutely sure your view will never have more than one form input? Probably still a bad idea though..

I cant find any recent articles talking about any advantages of form collections.. while strongly typed views are everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

The default model binder will do almost everything you need it to do. I resorted to the `FormCollection` once - only to later figure out how to bind arrays of elements into a collection on the *ViewModel*.

Just go *ViewModel*. Better all around, for every reason enumerated.

Answer (score 3):

With `form collection` you will be able to get all the values inside the form. There can be situations where you may need to pass some additional values from the form which may not be part of your `view model`.

Just take an example of passing  10 hidden values from the form. The form collection makes sense.

The only difficulty that you may face is type casting. All form collection items that you get will be string; you may need to `type cast` based on your requirement.

Also model state validation is another area where you may face a challenge.

Comment: If they are values that are being passed to your controller to operate on then they should be apart of the model IMHO. It is clear they relate to the model in some sense. If not the main model than some sort of base model.

Answer (score 2):

Well with **Forms Collection** you will find a quick way to get the values of a form. Otherwise you have to create a class that mimics the Form Fields and people are sometime lazy to create custom classes for less important/rarely used Forms.

No there is no extra benefit (in fact limited) of forms collection over a custom class as action parameters and it should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: It does seem like it was either laziness, or lack of knowledge about how to use MVC....

Answer (score 2):

You can always add the form collection properties to your method signatures. They will automatically be populated by form values with corresponding keys.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Sometimes, it can be useful. Here's an example:

Let's say we have in our db "`date_and_time_field`".

In Razor View, we want to use two form fields. The first one "Date" (maybe with jQuery UI Datepicker). The second one "Hour".

In the Controller Action, we *compose* the "date_and_time_field" by means of `Request.Form["Date"]` and `Request.Form["Hour"]`.

There are other scenarios where it can be useful:

- A cross-table (with checkBoxes in Razor view)
- The collection `Request.Unvalidated().Form` (maybe this is not part of your question: I don't wanna be off-topic)

Comment: Wouldn't your view model just have separate properties for date and time in that case, and the controller would compose the datetime from the ViewModel's properties?

Comment: Suppose you are working with a database-first approach. You create (and, sometimes, update), by means of the wizard, the edmx and the model class. You extend the Model partial class with the "hour" property (just "get", in order to be showed in the View with the hour-format). In the Controller Action (Edit [HttpPost]), you compose the "date_and_time_field" thanks to Request.Form.

Answer (score 2):

Responding to the title question: yes.

There are some situations that `FormCollection` needs to be used. For instance, suppose a `ViewModel` that has a property that implements the 1 to N relation (in concrete case, a `TimesheetViewModel` with `ICollection<TimesheetEntryViewModel>`), and the Controller has to perform a validation between the time entries to not get a time collision between the end time of an entry and the start time of the following entry. To mark a related entry with a validation error, how can be the line index be retrieved?

Well, with the default model binding, the index value is lost in the Controller logic. Fortunately, `FormController` stores the index you used in the *View* and a more specific validation can be done.

Answer (score 0):

There are type of SPA apps where you have no idea about your model (there is no ViewModel at all and views are created dynamically (for short ;))), so FormCollection is your only choice where you implement custom post validation having entire page input values...
If your view has a knowledge about the model then, of course, you can use your concrete ViewModel object. That's easy ;)