# Using HtmlHelpers in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm going to use MVC4 for my project in future. I doubt using @Html helpers instead of using classic way like this:

```
@Html.labelfor(....)
```

or

```
<label for="xx">name</label>
```

Is it necessary to use html helpers?

Comment: Nothing forces you to use html helpers, they are just that - Helpers.

Comment: **[HTML helpers helps you to submit your View Model to Controller. In this way you can avoid the use of Form Collection and Form Collection is not a good option for Unit Testing Purpose. Click here to check more details.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002022/is-there-any-good-reason-to-use-formcollection-instead-of-viewmodel/17203239#17203239)**

Comment: @PKKG That is not what they are for.. you can just as easily not use HTML Helpers and it will bind fine..

Comment: @SimonWhitehead : You are right. +1 BUT, once you are used to implement HTML helpers. It's advantage side.

Comment: I still don't get your point. They are used for _helping build html_ ... that is completely different to the model binder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You use HTML helpers in a view to render HTML content. An HTML helper, in most cases, is just a method that returns a string. You can build an entire ASP.NET MVC application without using a single HTML helper; however, **HTML helpers make your life as a developer easier**. By taking advantage of helpers, you can build your views with far less work.
>   In the ASP.NET MVC world, HTML helpers are the equivalent of ASP.NET Web Form controls. Like a Web Form control, an HTML helper enables you to encapsulate the rendering of HTML. However, unlike a Web Form control, HTML helpers are extremely
>   lightweight. For example, an HTML helper does not have an event model and does not
>   use view state.

-- "ASP.NET MVC Framework UNLEASHED" by Stephen Walther

Answer (score 4):

They are exactly what they say they are - helpers. But they do save you on coding time IMO. You picked the LabelFor example to demonstrate your point but let me give you my example. Is it easier to write:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName, new { @class = "input-block-level", placeholder = "Last Name" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LastName)
```

Or

```
<input class="input-block-level" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Last Name must be a string with a maximum length of 50." data-val-length-max="50" data-val-required="The Last Name field is required." id="LastName" name="LastName" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" value="">
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="LastName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

In other words, helpers are very useful in keeping the code clean and easy to maintain while saving you coding time in the process.