# Is it acceptable to have a ViewModel in MVC pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have recently finished a project using MVC framework (ASP.NET MVC). The project used a separate DTO classes to be passed to View by the controller. The model pretty much stayed away from the view. This draws a connotation between the VM in MVVM and my DTO's. A retrospective thought on the project suggests I could not have done without the DTO's (since, my model is very much in Application Tier and can not be passed to Web Tier because of security reasons).

So here is my question - Is VM (View Model) a necessity in MVC? Are there production applications where controllers pass Model directly to the View?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any good reason to use FormCollection instead of ViewModel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002022/is-there-any-good-reason-to-use-formcollection-instead-of-viewmodel)

Answer (score 3):

> The purpose of a view model is quite straightforward—it is a model that is specifically
>   designed for use within a view. **It provides a simplified interface on top of the domain
>   model that keeps decision-making in the view to a minimum**.

-- "ASP.NET MVC 4 In Action"

> When you have dozens of distinct values to pass to a view, the same flexibility that allows you to 
>   quickly add a new entry, or rename an existing one, becomes your worst enemy .You are left on your 
>   own to track item names and values; you get no help from Microsoft IntelliSense and compilers .
>   **The only proven way to deal with complexity in software is through appropriate design. So defining an object model for each view helps you track what that view really needs. I suggest you define a 
>   view-model class for each view you add to the application**.

-- "Programming Microsoft ASP.NET MVC" by Dino Esposito

In every ASP.NET MVC tutorial and book, authors are believe that ViewModels are necessary. In my experience, without ViewModels my projects became rigid and fragile; so, I strongly recommend you using ViewModels in your projects.

Comment: Thank you Abbas for the rep. Going by what you are saying is MVC almost always is best to use with a VM. So are we looing at a pattern which has deficiency. Since, almost always MVC does not work with just a M it requires a VM to be practically usable. Your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

Conside if you have an employee table

```
EmpID
Fname
Lname
DeptID
DesigID
Email
Phone
```

So if you will be having a class to represent this table. You can treat this as a model to view. EF will get you the List and you can display in the view.

1. The ViewModels helps to achieve some business requirements.Suppose you need to show name as First + Last , so every time you need to do concatenation, instead you can have a property which returns the value.
2. Also we can use data annotations, to do a basic validations.
3. We can reuse this in different places and no need for creating anonymous classes which will be easy in beginning, but difficult to maintain after 4-5 months.
4. Also while converting to JSON etc, we can avoid passing entity information . Consider you need to show (using json), employees with email id only and don't have any view model, so we need to serialize the entire List which include personal contact number, which is not required to share.
5. You can also have wrapper classes. You need to show Employee details with attendance, You need to club two tables and create an anonymous class which is very costly to maintain.

So I believe its always a good practice to use View Models instead of passing EF objects directly to views

Comment: VeeKayBee isn't model supposed to do business validations? The validations on view are almost always done using jQuery or any other framework..

Comment: what you are doing is using jquery is just a  basic validations for your inputs. There are some kind of requirements for business purpose, can be changed from time to time. One can say it is possible to handle these things in jquery, but while changing you need to struggle. View models helps to maintain application on the fly with less effort to new persons to your project.