# Render HTML5 <audio> tag with Html.ActionLink() helper or the Url.Action() helper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Which one should i use and why?

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click here to listen track 1", "Display", new { id = 1 })
<a href="/song/display/1">Click here to listen track 1</a>
```

Comment: What's ur point of View ?

Comment: I'd use the ActionLink in case you wanted to extend the ActionLink Helper later on in your code (unlikely, but it's possible).

Comment: **[You can easily bind the *View Model* and Post it to Action method. So View Model binding is easy in case of Helper method, Instead passing the FormCollection using `Anchor` Tag.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002022/is-there-any-good-reason-to-use-formcollection-instead-of-viewmodel/17203239#17203239)**

Answer (score 1):

Using raw anchor tag markup will break as soon as you change your site's routing config such that the addresses change.  You should use one of the following:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click here to listen track 1", "Display", new { id = 1 })
```

OR

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Display", new { id = 1 })">Click here to listen track 1</a>
```

I tend to use the bottom style, because I like my `cshtml` files to be more `html` than `cs`, but that's just my preference.