# TempData value not persisting if used in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, tempdata

I am using

```
TempData["hdn"] = "1";
```

in controller

If I use this

```
 @{
      var hdn = (string)TempData["hdn"];
  }
```

in View, `TempData["hdn"]` value in getting null in POST. If I skip this code in view it persists in POST. Why this is happening?

Comment: How often do you access `TempData`? `TempData` is used to persist things between calls, but is cleared once accessed. (You may want to either pass the value in with a query parameter or your form submission). (See http://www.squaredroot.com/2007/12/20/mvc-viewdata-vs-tempdata/)

Comment: **[You should not use Form Values. You could select suggestion given by Satpal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002022/is-there-any-good-reason-to-use-formcollection-instead-of-viewmodel/17203239#17203239)**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TempData values are cleared after they are read.

if you want the value back in the controller after you have read it in the view, then you will need to include it in a hidden field and then read it out from the form values.

something like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hdn" value="@hdn" />
```

Then in your controller, you can do:

```
var hdn = Request.Form["hdn"]
```

HTH

Comment: And here's a pointer to more info on passing data in MVC: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394711%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 10):

`TempData` is like ViewData but with a difference. It can contain data between two successive requests, after that they are destroyed.

If you want to keep `TempData` value the use

```
TempData.Keep()
```

Example:

```
var hdn= TempData["hdn"]; //it is marked for deletion
TempData.Keep("hdn"); //unmarked it
```

[MSDN Docs for Keep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ee703522%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

A `TempData` key & value set will be deleted after it has been called. Satpal talked about Keep, but you can also use Peek if you want to be explicit about every time you want to retrieve it without having it deleted.

```
TempData.Peek(String)
```

Example:

```
var hdnNotDeleted = TempData.Peek["hdn"];
```

[MSDN  Documentation for Peek](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ee923661%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If your controller action returns a `ViewResult`, and you are tempted to put data into `TempData`,
Don’t do That.Use `ViewData/ViewBag`, instead, in this case.
`TempData` is meant to be a very **short-lived instance**, and you should only use it during the current and the subsequent requests only. Since `TempData` works this way, you need to know for sure what the next request will be, and `Redirecting` to another `View` is the only time you can guarantee this. Therefore, the only scenario where using `TempData` will Reliably work is when you are Redirecting. So Keep in Mind.

The best ever explanation: http://sampathloku.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-to-use-aspnet-mvc-tempdata-properly.html