# How to pass Formcollection and Model value at the same time from view to controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have cshtml page having code like this

```
model Kouponer.Models.person_T  
@using (Html.BeginForm("BuynowForm", "Home"))
{    
    <label>@Model.name</label>
    <label>address</label>
    @Html.TextBox("address")<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
}
```

And my current actionresult method is

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BuynowForm(FormCollection col)
{  string address = col["address"];
        return View();
}
```

Here I will get only the formcollection values. How to pass the model along with
the formcollection?

Comment: [Please read this link](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx) Basically, you should NEVER use FormCollection

Comment: @br4d, care to explain why someone should NEVER use FormCollection? Are there performance concerns or some other issue?

Comment: @enki.dev [Check this other stackoverflow link for way more detailed response than I could provide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002022/is-there-any-good-reason-to-use-formcollection-instead-of-viewmodel)

Comment: @br4d There is one time I like to use FormCollection. When I want to have a Get and Post method, but I don't need parameters for either... putting FormCollection as a parameter for the post fixes that problem. Of course in that case I don't actually use it... it's just there to make sure I don't get a compilation error for having duplicate method signatures.

Answer (score 4):

In the [`Controller`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) class of [`System.Web.Mvc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc(v=vs.118).aspx) namespace there is an [`HttpRequestBase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestbase(v=vs.118).aspx) property called [`Request`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492753(v=vs.118).aspx) with all the data of the current http request. Among its properties, there is the [`NameValueCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection(v=vs.110).aspx) property called [`Form`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestbase.form(v=vs.110).aspx) you are looking for.

The usage would be something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BuynowForm(person_T model)
{
    string addressFromModel = model.Address;
    string addressFromRequest = Request.Form["address"];
    return View();
}
```

Comment: @mamodom now I am getting value in addressFromRequest. I need to get the value of that <label>@Model.name</label> inside actionresult. but its value is not getting. Is there any change we have to make in view? –

Comment: May I ask why you want to get those values from the `NameValueCollection` and no from the `person_T` object?

Comment: I got it when I used  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.name, new { @class = "hidden" })

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm completely missing something, you should simply be able to add the model type on the controller's sig.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BuynowForm(Models.person_T model, FormCollection col)
{  string address = col["address"];
   string addressFromModel = model.Address;
   return View();
}
```

However, it seems redundant to need the FormCollection object if you are going to be using model binding. I would read the link given in the comments and just go with model binding.