# Taking non-model information from a text box and passing it through a Actionlink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

So I am trying to set up a website that has questions, answers, and comments, much like stackoverflow. right now, I am trying to get comments to work correctly. I have decided that I will try to use an `ActionLink` to send the comment text to the `controller`. Is there any way that you can do this without invoking the model fields?

Comment: This is easily done with a FormCollection, as I will show below, but I don't think it's what you want in the long run. It's better to bind the objects to a model and follow the MVC design pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simple form submit, then grab your submitted data via a `FormCollection`

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult SubmitComment(FormCollection collection)
{
   string comment = collection["comment"];
}
```

and for your view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitComment", "CommentsController"))
{
   @Html.TextBox("comment")
   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

In my opninon you are better off binding this data to a model in the long run. See this link for more details : [Is there any good reason to use FormCollection instead of ViewModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002022/is-there-any-good-reason-to-use-formcollection-instead-of-viewmodel)

Answer (score 0):

What if you place your inputs to `<form>` tag ?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddComent", "CommentsController"))
{
   @Html.TextBox("comment")
   <input type="submit" value="Post Your Comment" />
}
```

P.S.
Other option (that i prefer) would be to send Ajax Post calls with JQuery: `$.post("@Url.Action("$Action", "$Controller")", { $parameter: $data });`